# Counter in FASM assembly

Tags: optimization, performance, assembly

I am making a simple counter in assembly. It counts to a billion and exits. However, the performance of this is really horrible. A Java application (that does the same) outperforms it by around 10x. How can I optimize this code?

```
include 'include/win32ax.inc'

section '.data' Data readable writeable
  outhandle  DD ?
    inhandle   DD ?
    incr DD 0
    numwritten DD ?
    inchar     DB ?
    numread DD ?
section '.text' code readable executable 
  start:
     invoke  AllocConsole
      invoke  GetStdHandle,STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
         mov [outhandle],eax
       invoke  GetStdHandle,STD_INPUT_HANDLE
        mov [inhandle],eax
        invoke  WriteConsole,[outhandle],"Starting...",11,numwritten,0

        jmp loopcount
       loopcount:
       inc [incr]
       cmp [incr], 1000000000;1 billion. ;]
       jne loopcount
       invoke  WriteConsole,[outhandle],"   Done count",13,numwritten,0
       invoke  ReadConsole,[inhandle],inchar,2,numread,0
       invoke ExitProcess,0
.end start
```

Comment: I edited my answer after you accepted it.

Comment: @ChrisW i know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load `[incr]` into a register instead, for example `eax`, and increment the register.

Instead of `cmp [incr], 1000000000` and `jne`, try loading 1000000 into the `ecx` register and using the [`loop`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Loop_Instructions) opcode.

The advice above to use `loop` is probably obsolete. Instead it may be faster to do load 1000000 into a register like `ebx`, and do a `dec ebx` and `jnz loop`.

Intel's [Branch and Loop Reorganization to Prevent Mispredicts](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/branch-and-loop-reorganization-to-prevent-mispredicts) seems to recommend you code a loop like this ...

```
loop_top:
... do work inside the loop here ...
cmp ebx,1000000
jz loop_end ; happens rarely
inc ebx
jmp loop_top ; happens often
loop_end:
```

... in order to optimize the branch prediction.

Unrolling the loop might make it faster. In fact given how dumb the algorithm is, the best optimization is to immediately 1000000 to [incr] without looping.